# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate to load a network file

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

We are using a web browser to show a pdf file located in a folder on the network. The code looks like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(New Uri("\\host\path\to\file.pdf"))
```

This works fine, but now I have to use a specific user to access this file and I don't know how to include the user name, password and domain in the URI. Is it posible to add user credentials to the URI? Can I use another variant of Navigate method to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a password protected shared network folder using VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321128/how-to-open-a-password-protected-shared-network-folder-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the UNC path, like this:

```
Dim networkPath As String = "\\server\path\to\file.pdf"
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm already using an UNC path. I've corrected the slashes in the question. How can I specify the user/password?